# Mixing conditionals confusion

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context, sequence-of-tenses, conditionals

Using mix conditionals : should I use "were" or "are"  in the following:

1-They wouldn't be famous in the way that they( are) now if they hadn't been serious.

2- They wouldn't be famous in the way that they( were )now if they hadn't been serious.

Comment: Can you check your examples   Do you mean to have "that" in the first and missing in the second?  To you intend the tense to change from "are" to "were"?  The "conditional" part of this is the same, the only difference I can see are in a little subordinate clause, that isn't part of the "conditional" grammar.  So the questions is a little unclear to me

Comment: @James K Thanks for the note .Actually I just forgot to write "that". What I want to focus on the question is using "are" versus "were" to suit the context .

Answer (score 0):

The conditional aspect is irrelevant here.  It doesn't matter that the clauses are embedded in a conditional construction.

The relative clause is about the present time (it says "now") so it should use the present tense.

Comment: The problem is not that the word "now" is proximate (see my answer for a counterexample), it is that the use of the conditional "were" is not possible because the place it occurs is not in a conditional clause.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is correct, use the present tense in the subordinate clause here..

"Were" is sometimes used with conditional constructions, in the clause with the condition:

"**Were they not serious, they would not be famous in the way that they are now.**"

**"They would also be famous if they were serious now."**

However, that is different than the use in (2).  "...that they are now" is not the clause that describes the condition, but further describes "the way [that they are famous]".

As usual, you can "test" the agreement of clauses by removing them from the sentence and adding parts back in to make them stand on their own:

(now) **They are now famous.**

(now) They were now famous.  [incorrect]